# Remove default Hover Blue color in a Wpf button

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm trying to remove the default hover button hover effect in my wpf application this is my code:

```
    <Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

I can set opacity correctly but the blue effect still remains, how i can do?